# How to merge DataFrames, using multiple columns and additionally using conditions from DataFrames columns use operator AND?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I have the part of code that works well in MS SQL:

```
    select *  from table_1
    full outer join table_2 on 
                                table_1.Name = table_2.Name_2 and
                                table_1.Qty = table_2.Qty_2 and
                                table_1.[Month] = table_2.Month_2 and
                                table_1.class = 'X' and
                                table_2.class_2 = 'Y'
```

But i need to create the same code in python and i am trying to do this:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(table_1, table_2, how='outer', left_on=['Name', 'Qty', 'Month'], right_on=['Name_2', 'Qty_2', 'Month_2'])
```

But how to add this condition `and table_1.class = 'X' and table_2.class_2 = 'Y'`for the merge **without using where, it will give a different result**:

```
& (table_1['class'] == 'X') & (table_2['class_2'] == 'Y')
```

Comment: You can just pass the filtered dataframes as arguments of the merge:

`df_merge = pd.merge(table_1['class'] == 'X', table_2['class_2'] == 'Y',
how='outer', left_on=['Name', 'Qty', 'Month'], right_on=['Name_2', 'Qty_2', 'Month_2'])`

Comment: @marinovik, thanks for answer, but I get the error -> KeyError: 'Name_2' when use your construction of code. If leaving only join by columns Name/Name_2, and save the filter condition, I get the same error

Comment: This is because you might not have any `Name_2` column in your `table_2` dataframe.  Can you check it? What you are saying in this code is: "merge these 2 filtered dataframes on the these provided columns for `table_1` and `table_2`. So all these columns must be present in their respective dataframes.

Comment: @marinovik, I found the reason, the line of code must be like this `df_merge = pd.merge(table_1[table_1['class'] == 'X'], table_2[table_2['class_2'] == 'Y'], how='outer', left_on=['Name', 'Qty', 'Month'], right_on=['Name_2', 'Qty_2', 'Month_2'])`, and all works well. Thanks for help.

Comment: Oh of course! That is the proper filtering mate, my bad. Cheers